# Radical integral question calculus

Tags: calculus, integration

I have a question in calculus.

Let $F(x)=\int_1^\sqrt{x} t^2\cos( \pi t)dt$ Find $F'(4)$

I know $F'(X$)  $=\int_1^\sqrt{x} x^2\cos( \pi x)dx$

So I made $u=x^{\frac{1}{2}}$

and I got

$u^2\cos\pi(u)$

which is

$F'(x)=x^{1/4}\cdot \left(\frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}}\right)\cdot \cos\pi\sqrt{x}$

when I plugged in four I got

$F'(4)=\sqrt{2}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$

but did I do this correctly?

Comment: No, does not look right. You get $F'(x) = x^{1/4} \cos ( \pi/2) = 0$, basically. Which is incorrect. Currently you seem to have too many typos. Please fix those before someone can help. As it is currently, it will be quite hard for someone to help you.

Comment: I do not know if this makes sense but I used chain rule Ill explain.

Comment: I made u=x^(1/2) so that I take derivative of x^(1/2) because of F'(x)=f(u)(x)times(u'(x)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your post is very confusing: but I think I finally follow:

Note we have substituted $u = \sqrt x$ and $du = \dfrac 1{2\sqrt x  }dx$

giving us $u^2\cos\pi(u)\,du$

So your expression for  $F'(x)$ is off and needs to be, no in terms of $x$: $$F'(x)=(\sqrt x)^2\cdot  \cos\pi\sqrt{x}\cdot \left(\frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}}\right)$$

Now evalate $F'(4)$:

The procedure is a little mixed up and the *exposition* was a little confusing.

Comment: Since the integrand is  $t^2 \cos(\pi t)$, shouldn't the first factor be $(\sqrt{x})^2$, rather than $\sqrt{\sqrt{x}}$ ?

Comment: @Reckless Yes indeed, corrected: I just found the exposition really difficult to follow and confused myself in the process!

Comment: you are right it was confusing because I was confused myself. Thanks for the help I think my mistake was that in my substitution of the value especially u^2.

Comment: hhm at F'(4) I got 4(1/4) for my answer

Comment: $F'(4) = (\sqrt 4)^2 \cdot \cos(2 \pi) \cdot\left(\frac 1{2\sqrt 4}\right) = 2^2 \cdot 1 \cdot \frac 1{2\cdot 2} = 4/4 = 1$. That looks right to me!

Comment: Nice when you can help the OP through their confusion! +1

Comment: Yes, your substitution $u = \sqrt x$ was fine...the one error was, essentially, needing for $u^2 = (\sqrt x)^2 = x$

Comment: @Amzoti - Yes, Fernando is a very responsive, hard working student.

Answer (score 1):

The integral bound is from 1 to 2 because, if you have gotten to u-substitution, u becomes sqrt(x) and you evaluate u(4)=sqrt(4)=2 and then use integration by parts. Here is a link to integration by parts:

http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcII/IntegrationByParts.aspx

And the derivative should be x*cos(pi*sqrt(x)) because of Leibniz's rule.

Comment: I've not learned integration by parts yet...

Comment: Neither have I.

Comment: Oops, I screwed up Leibniz rule. Multiply by the derivative of sqrt(x) and it should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

This is an indirect application of the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus which is quickly passed through in many introductory texts.  You have an integral function  $F(x) = \int^{x}_{1} f(t) dt$; since $t^2 \cos(\pi t )$ is continuous everywhere, we can safely say that  $F'(x) = f(x)$ .

When the upper limit is a *function* of $x$, the FTC will let us write $\int^{u}_{1} f(t) dt  =  F(u) - F(1)$.  When we differentiate this with respect to $x$, the Chain Rule gives us  $$\frac{d}{dx}\int^{u}_{1} f(t) dt  =  \frac{d}{dx} [F(u) - F(1)]  =  \frac{dF}{du} \cdot \frac{du}{dx}  = f(u(x)) \cdot \frac{du}{dx}$$

So for this problem, 
$$\frac{d}{dx}\int^{\sqrt{x}}_{1} t^2 \cos(\pi t ) dt    = (\sqrt{x})^2 \cos(\pi \sqrt{x} )) \cdot \frac{d}{dx}(\sqrt{x}).$$

To answer your question, you would complete the differentiation and evaluate the result at  x = 4 .

(I'll mention, incidentally, that a problem of this type is a **favorite** final exam question.)

Comment: thanks for the help and I will be sure to study it for my final which will be soon.....